# Typecasting Different Types into One Type

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, long-integer

long is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. Is Long a 128-bit signed two's complement integer? I just wanted to confirm this before proceeding.

```
Long l = 6;
int i = 4;
Integer ii = 2;
l += (l/i) * ii;
```

I was wondering where I would need to typecast in order to get back 3, instead of 2.

I tried the following:

```
l += (long) (((double) l/i) * ii);
```

When I typecast `l/i` with `double`, I get back `1`, instead of `1.5`?

Lets say I was to typecast a Long, that was the largest number for a Long, with (long), what would happen since long is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.

Comment: size depends on your compiler. use sizeof(). Also add tag `C`, or `C++`

Comment: It is neither C or C++. I added a Java tag.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `sizeof` is not an accurate way to determine the number of value bits that an integer uses to represent, due to the possible presense of padding bits.

Comment: @dalwh you can change Tags

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Yes, Also I was commenting with respect to C/C++. OP forgot to add language tags.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Perhaps we could continue discussing C and/or C++ in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27685/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-grijesh-chauhan).

Answer (score 4):

`long` (lower case) is a primitive type 64-bit integer. `Long` (upper-case) is a reference type (object) that wraps a `long` (lower-case). So `Long`'s encode their data in a `long` and are hence 64-bit as well. If you want > 64-bit precision, look into [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which offers arbitrarily high precision.

Your problem does not come from incorrect casting within the division statement but from the cast to `long` at the end:

```
l += (long) (((double) l/i) * ii);
       ^
       here
```

The result of `(((double) l/i) * ii)` is a `double` of value 3.0. Due to the peculiarities of floating-point arithmetic, this becomes 2 when it is cast to a `long`.

In order to solve this, use `Math.round` instead of a typecast:

```
 l += Math.round(((double) l/i) * ii);
```

Comment: If long and Long are both 64-bit integers, is there a reason to use Long besides all the methods it comes with?

Comment: Long is a reference type, so it can used in many places where primitive types cannot. For instance, in generics (e.g. `ArrayList<Long>` works but `ArrayList<long>` does not). In common practice, however, it offers no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Your `(l/i) * ii` means power? If so, maybe you should use `BigDecimal`. By the way, `1/i` equals 0; use `1.0/i` instead.

Comment: I was thinking of using BigDecimal and BigInteger because I needed something that would hold a 64-bit positive integer. How big does BigDecimal go up to?

I also noticed that they with things in String, so I was wondering which is was better?
- Convert all the integers I use into BigDecimal/BigInteger to make life simpler
- Keep the different types (int, long, double, etc) to save resources

Comment: as the api saied,BigInteger provide arbitrary-precision integers,it ca hold arbitrary big integers

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Is was better? Convert all the integers I use into BigDecimal/BigInteger to make life simpler OR keep the different types (int, long, double, etc) to save resources

Comment: It depends.If your integer is bigger than 64bit,You don't have any other options but to use BigInteger,Operations on BigInteger is more expensive than that on primitives.

Comment: If your integer has no chance to exceed 64bit,use long,never use BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks again. Going back to... l += (l/i) * ii; If I was to only use BigInteger and BigDecimal since the numbers are so large, should I just stick with BigDecimal? Basically, I am trying to ask if there is a disadvantage to using BigDecimal over BigInteger?

Answer (score 0):

`Long` is a class containing constructors, methods, and constants relevant to the `long` primitive object (eg. `Long.MAX_VALUE` which will give you the maximum value that a `long` can represent). When you convert a `long` to a `Long`, you're converting from a value type to a reference type. The number of bits used to represent the values won't change.